# How to find elements by XPath inside #document

Tags: javascript

I have an html page with `<embed src=......>`. Inside it `#document` is used and nested html page is there. How to find elements by XPath inside `#document`

I am trying using JavaScript

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'Recaptcha')]')]"));
```

[screenshot of a DOM tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGWgL.png)

Comment: are you using protractor?

Comment: Do you really have to use an <embed> element here?

Comment: extending @Kaiido 's comment. You can use iframe to integrate external HTML from same origin or even other origin. You can easily switch to the iframe's context and use xpath  to find elements inside

Comment: I want to add a button inside the <embed> element dynamically. Like this:      <embed><input type="button" id="cbtn" onClick="verifyCallback()"></embed>.

Comment: We are trying to automate a website  which is having the <embed> tag( refer screenshot attached). We are using java selenium for this.

Answer (score 2):

XPath won't be able to access the content of replaced elements from the main document.

If your content is loaded in accordance with Same-Origin-Policies, then you may use XPath from the replacing document directly. But <embed> is a weird beast... 
Unlike <object> or <iframe> elements, it doesn't expose a `contentDocument` property, but instead a `getSVGDocument()` method. But as its name says, this method is intended to get an SVG Document, and some browsers (at least Chrome) will refuse to give you anything from an HTML document <sub>([while Firefox is ok with it](https://jsfiddle.net/852czn9L/1/))</sub>

So to have it to work in these browsers, you would need to use an other element, for instance an <iframe>. From there, you should be able to get its contentDocument and set it as the root of your XPath query:

```js
iframe.onload = e => {
  const doc = iframe.contentDocument; // get the contentDocument
  // evaluate XPath
  const query = doc.evaluate("//div[contains(@id,'Recaptcha')]')]", doc);
  const node = query.iterateNext();
  // ... do something with node
}
```

[**As a fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/guakh876/) since Stack-Snippets do not allow SOP-friendly frames.

Comment: Can you kindly provide java selenium code for this.

Comment: @AmanAnand hum nope. I don't know Java. Your question is tagged javascript, I answer in javascript.

Comment: I want to add a button inside the <embed> element dynamically. Like this: <embed><input type="button" id="cbtn" onClick="verifyCallback()"></embed>.    Is it possible using javascript?